# How to exclude a directory from autofill in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

After exporting my project to Android a directory named `.godot/exported` appeared in the root of my Godot project. It seems to contain some cache for the resources I have exported.

Problem is, autofill gets scenes from it when I type stuff like `get_tree().change_scene_to_file` and it messes with my ability to find the resources I need.

Do you know if there is an option in Godot 4 which allows users to exclude specific directories from autofill?

[image]

**Edit1:** I am using Godot v4.1.1 under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I thought this information might be useful.

I have `.godot/` directory in my `.gitignore` and the files from there are not tracked by git but are still popping up in the autofill for the `change_scene_to_file` method. I checked that `preload()` doesn't show resources from `.godot/` directory as [this Godot doc page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.1/tutorials/best_practices/project_organization.html) describes but it is not my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Godot 4 shouldn't be showing you the contents of the .godot folder (it does not by default). Thus something else went wrong.

Anyway, you can tell Godot to ignore a folder and all its contents by adding a file with the name `.gdignore` inside fo it. *This is briefly mentioned in [Project organization](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/best_practices/project_organization.html).*

Comment: Thanks for your input but I have .godot folder in my .gitignore and the files from there are still popping up in the autofill, so this is not the answer.